# Probability of A to beat B knowing that A beats C so many times and C beats B so many times

Tags: probability

Is there a formula to find the probability for A to beat B knowing the probability of both against a common opponent C?

If so can you explain to me a bit about it? :)

Below some example based on common sense:

1. If A beat C $80\%$ and C beats B $80\%$, then A beats B $\sim95\%$
2. If A beat C $50\%$ and C beats B $20\%$, then A beats B $20\%$
3. If A beat C $20\%$ and C beats B $20\%$, then A beats B $\sim5\%$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rock beats scissors all of the time and Paper never beats scissors... so do you suppose that means that Rock beats paper all of the time?

Comment: Magnus Carlsen is considered the best chess player in the world. But, Ian Nepomniachtchi has beaten Magnus three times, drawn four times, and never lost to him.

Comment: In case the comments aren't clear enough... No.  There is no formula since there is not nearly enough information.  Being "likely to beat" another player is not a transitive relation.

Comment: The answer of Matthew found exactly what I was unable to put into a formula (because I'm bad at math)! :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments aren't wrong that it isn't necessarily safe to assume that "beatability" is transitive.  But it is a valid mathematical question to ask what you can do with this data if it is all that you have.

Let's make an assumption that C presents a consistent challenge.  Therefore, we might also say that A shows up to any game with enough "oomph" to beat C with probability $p$ and that B shows up to any game without enough "oomph" to beat C with probability $q$.  Let's also assume that those two events are independent.  That might be a lot to assume, but there we are.

Therefore, with probabiltiy $pq$, A will be better than C and B won't be as good as C.  Therefore, we will say that A will beat B under those circumstances.  On the other hand, with probability $(1-p)(1-q)$, A will be worse than C but B will be better than C.  Under those circumstances, we will say that B will beat A.  We won't consider the other two cases of either both A and B being strong and both being weak.  Therefore, our super-rough estimate that A will beat B is $$\frac{pq}{pq+(1-p)(1-q)}$$

To put this estimate up against the three (or two, really) tests:

> If A beat C 80% and C beats B 80%, then A beats B ~95%

$$\frac{.64}{.64+.04}\approx94.1\%$$

> If A beat C 50% and C beats B 20%, then A beats B 20%

$$\frac{.1}{.1+.4}=20\%$$

> If A beat C 20% and C beats B 20%, then A beats B ~5%

$$\frac{.04}{.04+.64}\approx5.9\%$$

Comment: Thank you Matthew! :D